# Could not install package 'Stripe.net 39.27.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, stripe-payments

i am installing nuget package strip.net but when installing it give me this error in visoul studio , i did not find any solution plz need your solution

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Stripe.net 39.27.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.         0

Comment: If the package cannot target .NET 4.5.2, you cannot use that package. Have you considered using a newer .NET Framework instead?

Comment: If it is [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stripe.net/) package, then the minimum supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.1.

Comment: Last version that supports .NET 4.5.1 is [37.35.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stripe.net/37.35.0). I don't know what the updates give you so maybe try this older version instead?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen could you plzz tell me how to update .netframework into newer version

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i add with stripe version 37.0.0 so is there any issue to using old version of stripe as i am working in stripe payment gateway  because i successfully install the old version of stripe

Comment: @FurqanShaheen to update your .NET Framework version, see here for instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2019#change-the-target-framework (P.S. It's easy to google that, you shouldn't really need to ask us)

Comment: "is there any issue to using old version of stripe"...that depends on whether your code need to rely on features or bug fixes which exist in the new version, but not in the older version. For that you need to a) find out what the  maintainer of the package has changed between versions - they probably publish this somewhere on their site, and b) check whether your code requires any of that or not. If you're unsure, create some tests to verify the behaviour of your code. We can't do those steps for you, it's your task.

Comment: @ADyson ok i will check that if still i found some issue i will ask thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the latest nuget package [Stripe.net 39.27.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stripe.net/39.27.0) does not support your old target framework version `4.5.2`. It is designed by the nuget author.

[image]

**First**, see this of **Stripe.net 39.27.0**: The nuget package supports net framework >=4.6.1 and net standard>=2.0. Since your target framework is `4.5.2` and also `net standard 2.0` does not support `4.5.2` but supports >=`4.6.1`,[see this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), so you do not meet either of these conditions.

So the solution is to either downgrade your nuget package or upgrade the target framework version of your project.

**Solution**

**1)** downgrade your nuget package, try to install the nuget package [Stripe.net 37.35.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stripe.net/37.35.0) and it supports `net framework 4.5.2`.

**2)** upgrade your project's framework version. Right-click on your project-->**Properties**-->**Application**--> change **Target Framework** to `4.6.1`. And then you can install the latest nuget package `Stripe.net 39.27.0`.

[image]